# Значения по оси x пересекаются

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Есть следующий код для рисования столбчатой диаграммы.

```
heights = []
bars = []

# заполнение heights и bars
# ...

x = np.arange(len(bars))
y = heights
plt.xticks(x, bars)
plt.bar(x, y)
```

Однако `bars` содержит достаточно длинные имена, поэтому в результате при сохранении `plt.savefig()` получаю что-то подобное [image: скрину] (значения пересекаются). Как сделать так, чтобы они не пересекались? Например, писались на разной высоте или просто расширить ось x.

Comment: Лучше не делать настолько длинные обозначения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое решение - повернуть надписи:

```
plt.xticks(x, bars, rotation=45)
```

Update: если надписи выходят за границы, попробуйте добавить:

```
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)
```

либо добавить:
    plt.tight_layout()

Итого:

```
heights = [1, 5, 3, 4, 9]
bars = ['aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
'qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq', 'lllllllllllllllllllll']

x = np.arange(len(bars))
y = heights
plt.xticks(x, bars, rotation=45)
plt.bar(x, y)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('2222.png')
```

Получим:
[image: bar plot]

Comment: теперь они не пересекаются, но выходят за рамки изображения вниз)

Comment: @Павел весь код в вопросе приведите тогда. Мало ли, у вас tight layout включен или еще что. Я добавил в ответ добавление места для надписей.

Comment: Так у меня приведён по сути весь код, только тестовое заполнение `heights = [1, 5, 3, 4, 9]
bars = ['aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq', 'lllllllllllllllllllll']
`
и в конце `plt.savefig('./test.png')`

Comment: @Павел `plt.subplots_adjust` помогло?

Comment: `plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)` действительно растягивает, но недостаточно. Как посчитать сколько надо, чтобы вместилось? И не лучше уж тогда по оси x расширять сразу?

Comment: @Павел снова исправил ответ - tight_layout спасёт засчет "съедания" места для диаграммы.

Comment: вот, теперь нормально, спасибо. Доп. вопрос.: `tight_layout()` надо писать заново после каждого `plt.clf()`? (делаю много графиков, поэтому очищаю `plt`)

Comment: @Павел tight_layout упаковывает axes/subplots в фигуре. Поэтому перед каждым выводом (сохранением) фигуры я бы рекомендовал использовать этот метод.

Comment: ок, всё работает